# ASP.NET Core: Is there any way to call a method from an HTML form button?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, button, methods

I am trying to call my c# method from my HTML form that updates the database.

Here's my HTML form:

```
<form runat="server">
    <label for="Fornavn">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="Fornavn" name="Fornavn"><br>
    <label for="Efternavn">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="Efternavn" name="Efternavn"><br>
    <label for="Brugernavn">Brugernavn:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="Brugernavn" name="Brugernavn"><br><br>
    <a asp-action="updateDbTest"><button class="btn btn-primary">update</button></a>
</form>
```

And here is the method I am trying to call (`updateDbTest()`):

```
public void updateDbTest()
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    {
        String query = "INSERT INTO Bruger (Fornavn,Efternavn,Brugernavn) VALUES (@Fornavn,@Efternavn,@Brugernavn)";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, cnn))
        {
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fornavn", "abc");
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Efternavn", "abc");
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brugernavn", "abc");

             cnn.Open();
             int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

             // Check Error
             if (result < 0)
                 Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");
         }
     }
 }
```

EDIT: I wish to make the html form call the method `updateDbTest()` after it has been submitted via a clickable button. I then wish it to refresh the page, if possible.

I tried using `asp:button`, but that does not seem to work on ASP.NET Core. Any feedback is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. Do you want to call updateDbTest() when the form is submitted (in which case where do you then want to redirect to?) or do you want to simply run the updateDbTest() method on the server while remaining on the same page?

Comment: its called ajax you have to invoke a request.

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you elaborate?

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. I made an edit on the post to explain my problem in more detail. Thank you. @JasperKent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `<a>` at all. You just need an `<button>` (or an `<input type='submit'...`) inside the `<form>`.

When the button is clicked, the form will be submitted to the method specified by `asp-action` on the `<form>`.

If (as here) there is no `asp-action` on the `<form>` then it will be submitted to the action method with the same name as the one that created the form view, the difference between the two being that the form was generated with the `[HttpGet]` version of the method and will be called back with the `[HttpPost]` version.

It's still not clear whether `updateDbTest()` is the method you want call on form submission. If you are submitting to a different method, then simply call `updateDbTest()` directly in C# from this other method.

Since `updateDbTest()` doesn't look at any of the form data, then I would presume that it is not the method you are submitting to.

However, if `updateDbTest()` is the method you want to submit to, then it needs some work. An action method (i.e. a method called directly from the client) must have a return type of `IActionResult`, and then return instructions for what the client should display, typically either `return View(...);` or `return RedirectTo...(...);`